What does 0 volts mean for a Van de Graaf generator?
I am trying to understand how two different definitions of zero-voltage reconcile in the experimental setup of a Van de Graaf generator, or at least how I understand that it is being described.

Establish a voltage potential function by defining
$$V_{\infty }= 0\space V$$
and using the standard formula for change in voltage moving from infinity to the shell diameter ${r_{o}}$ is
$$ \Delta V  = -\int_{\infty }^{r_{o}}E \cdot dr = V_{r_{o}} - V_{\infty } $$
yielding after standard integration
$$ V_{r_{o}} = \frac{kQ}{r} $$

Defining the voltage of the Earth (which is not infinitely far away) to be
$$V_{earth} = 0\space V$$


When I read about Van de Graaf generators, a typical classroom demonstration generator has a documented voltage of about 400,000 V and a radius of about 11 cm.  The maximum voltage is calculated from a formula that references the maximum electric field strength in air before arcing occurs, which is about 3,400,000 V / m.  Relating maximum electric field to voltage based on zero-standard of Definition 1:
$$ E_{max} = \frac{kQ}{r^{2}} = \frac{V}{r} $$
gives
$$ V_{max} = E_{max} r = 3,400,000\space V \cdot 0.11\space m = 374,000 V $$
The operation of the demonstration generator usually involves touching a so-named grounding rod to the charged sphere, allowing the accumulated charge to drain.  So it seems that the 400,000 V specification in an equipment catalog is being referenced to Earth-ground Definition 2.  But the equations deriving this maximum voltage are based on ideas in Definition #1 referencing zero-voltage at infinity.
I thought that perhaps the voltage of the earth's surface, when formulated using Definition 1, might work out to be very close to 0.  However, comparing Q/r for the Van de Graaf generator and the Earth using information I found online about the charge of the Earth and charge on a Van der Waals generator (based on its capacitance) and ignoring the common scaling factor k, I found:
Q/r Van de Graaf generator: $6\space x\space 10^{-6}\space C / \space 0.11 \space m = 5.5\space x\space 10^{-5}\space C/m$
Q/r Earth surface: $5\space x\space 10^{5}\space C / \space 6.4\space x\space 10^{6} = 0.078 \space C \space / \space m$
What is the concept that I'm missing?

You are missing that fact that a grounded conductor (in this case the earth itself) near  a charged object will have its own local induced charge.

@mike stone Thanks, I've looked more and I found there is a method of images for this scenario.  But am I understanding correctly that the two independently-defined 0 voltages (Earth surface and at infinity) are the same?

A ground plane stretches to infinity, so yes they are the same.

Thank you so much, that makes a lot of sense!
